# How to get battery overall health in android?

Tags: java, android, percentage, battery, batterymanager

Given eg a Honeywell CT40 handheld, in its settings there is a separate section dedicated to the battery and all of its details (usage, capacity, temp, cycle and even SN), and there is shown the battery's overall health in percentage.
Is it possible to get this overall health in percentage programatically?
With a new battery it is between 96-100%, and for example a battery with 192 cycles it is 90-92%.
I do not need anything else, only this percentage with minimal permissons required, if there is an app already existing that does this can also be good, but didn't find any yet.
Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager) to get the status of battery health but you can only have status like :

```
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD -> "Cold"
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD -> "Dead"
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD -> "Good"
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT -> "Over heat"
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE -> "Over voltage"
        BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN -> "Unknown"
```

And you can check your device constructor if they offer special library to access to battery detailled informations like :
https://techdocs.zebra.com/mx/batterymgr/